# Rudin's definition of Radius of convergence of a power series

Tags: real-analysis

Rudin states that for a power series $ \sum c_n z^n$, ($c_n, z_n$ complex valued), for $\alpha = \displaystyle{\limsup_{n \to \infty}} \sqrt[n]{|c_n|}$, $R = \frac{1}{\alpha}$, then $ \sum c_n z^n$ converges if $|z| < R$, and diverges if $|z| > R$. He includes that (If $\alpha = 0$, $R = + \infty$, if $\alpha = +\infty$, $R = 0$.)

In one of his examples (3.40 a), he states that

$ \sum n^n z^n $ has $R= 0$.

Now clearly this sum only converges for a value of $z = 0$. But my question is more about whether this theorem is actually stating that this converges if $z = 0$.

I'm not sure if I'm overthinking it, but the prelude paragraph to this just states that if $z$ is in the interior of the circle of convergence, then it converges. But by this definition, there are no points in this radius of convergence. That is, a point $z \in \mathbb{C}$, such that $|z| < 0$.

But clearly for $z= 0$, this is a convergent series. But just going off of the definitions alone, I am led to believe that this sum converges for no values?

Just to reiterate, this question is really more about understanding definitions correctly. I understand this sum does converge for $z = 0$, but I seem to be clearly misinterpreting some statements of Rudin because I am led to this contradictory conclusion.

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Every power series $\sum a_nz^{n}$ converges for $z=0$ with sum $a_0$.

Comment: I understand. My question is more about what this definition implies.

Comment: If $R$ is the radius of convergence then $\sum c_n z^n$ may or may not converge for $|z| = R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: In my answer, I'm speaking more generally about a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n (z-c)^n$ with center $c$, not necessarily zero.

The power series will converge at $z$ if $z$ is in the interior of the interval of convergence.

This is not the same as saying "the series will converge **if and only if** $z$ is in the interior of the interval of convergence", which is not a true statement. If the series is centered at $c$ with radius $R$, it is guaranteed to converge on $(c-R, c+R)$. Convergence at $c-R$ and $c+R$ is possible, but not guaranteed. You can come up with examples where the series converges at both $c-R$ and $c+R$, at neither, at $c-R$ but not $c+R$, or at $c+R$ but not $c-R$. Convergence at endpoints has to be tested separately.

In this case, $c=0$ and $R=0$, so $c-R=c+R=0=c$. A series always converges at the center $c$, as you said.

Comment: Got it thanks! Appreciate the thorough answer.